# Add Property to Express Request Object

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, nestjs

I'm trying to add a property "forwardingUrl" to the Express request object.

I tried declaration merging by creating a file ./typing.d.ts:

```
declare namespace Express {
  export interface Request {
    forwardingUrl: string;
  }
}
```

in the editor I can use the property and access it but when I compile I get the following error:

```
Property 'forwardingUrl' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary>'.
```

What am I missing?

EDIT

The code where I get the error:

```
import { Middleware, Request } from '@tsed/common';
import { Request as ExpressRequest } from 'express';
@Middleware()
export class Wso2ForwardingUrlParser {
    async use(@Request() request: ExpressRequest) {
        if (request.header('X_FORWARDED_HOST') && request.header('X_FORWARDED_PREFIX')) {
            request.forwardingUrl = `https://${request.header('X_FORWARDED_HOST')}${request.header('X_FORWARDED_PREFIX')}`;
        }   else {
            request.forwardingUrl = '';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Request already exists https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request and this is Request<ParamsDictionary> but your is Express.Request.

Comment: Also @types/express https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/express exists.

Comment: Request<ParamsDictionary> extends Request so shouldn't it work?

Comment: @Zydnar I need to add a property to express.request

Comment: But `export interface Request {` does not have any "extends". Can you include the code where you get the Error, also show the imports.

Comment: @Zydnar added the code

Comment: you can either do `async use((@Request() request) as ExpressRequest) {` because I thnk typescript is reading incorrectly decorator or try to extend parameters inside <> like this: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/288692b272b695eda00a47f93339e1e16ee756b1/types/express/index.d.ts#L99

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add new model that extends Request

```
import {Request} from "@tsed/common";

export interface RequestModel extends Request {
    forwardingUrl: string
}
```

and then use it in method

```
import { Middleware, Request } from '@tsed/common';
import { Request as ExpressRequest } from 'express';
@Middleware()
export class Wso2ForwardingUrlParser {
    async use(@Request() request: RequestModel) {
        if (request.header('X_FORWARDED_HOST') && request.header('X_FORWARDED_PREFIX')) {
            request.forwardingUrl = `https://${request.header('X_FORWARDED_HOST')}${request.header('X_FORWARDED_PREFIX')}`;
        }   else {
            request.forwardingUrl = '';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same issue and solved it by adding `//@ts-ignore` just above the lines where the error is being thrown:

```
import { Middleware, Request } from '@tsed/common';
import { Request as ExpressRequest } from 'express';

@Middleware()
export class Wso2ForwardingUrlParser {
    async use(@Request() request: ExpressRequest) {
        if (request.header('X_FORWARDED_HOST') && request.header('X_FORWARDED_PREFIX')) {

            //@ts-ignore
            request.forwardingUrl = `https://${request.header('X_FORWARDED_HOST')}${request.header('X_FORWARDED_PREFIX')}`;

        }   else {

            //@ts-ignore
            request.forwardingUrl = '';
        }
    }
}
```

I would also recommend using a param decorator to get this value later in the code. Since you've already added this extra "forwardingUrl" property to the request instance via your middleware, create a param decorator like so:

```
// ./ForwardingUrlDecorator.ts

import { createParamDecorator } from '@nestjs/common';

export const ForwardingUrl = createParamDecorator((_data: any, req: any) => {
    return req.forwardingUrl;
});
```

Then in your controller you can grab that value without having to reference the entire express instance as a parameter in your methods:

```
import { Controller } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ForwardingUrl } from './ForwardingUrlDecorator';

@Controller()
export class YourController {

    @Get()
    public async getTheThing(@ForwardingUrl() forwardingUrl: string) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: I was just getting and setting the properties but love your suggestion of using the decorator this way.

Answer (score 0):

To add custom properties for Express Request Object in nestjs,

Create a new folder called express and add new file index.d.ts, Use the following,

```
export {};

export type _Foo = Foo;

declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface Request {
      foo: _Foo;
    }
  }
}
```